# Is there an input type for worksheet in HTML?

Tags: html

I want to know if there's an input type worksheet in html? For example like image below:

[image]

Comment: Worksheet meaning spreadsheet? Like Excel?

Comment: Yes sir. Like excel.

Comment: Please do [some research on your own](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) before asking. See [ask]. There's even [a site which is explicitly just about input types](https://inputtypes.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In short: no. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) is a list of the input types. If you want to make a spreadsheet input, you are going to have to make it yourself, or find a package that implements one.